# inner join multiple tables with multiple columns in linq query not works

Tags: sql-server, linq, join, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

I have met the following problems when I use join of multiple tables with multiple columns, I will encounter the error message "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query." around the "join T4".
[image]
In simple SQL world, the following SQL query is normal, and can be executed well.

```
select A.AColumn1, B.BColumn from TableA A 
inner join TableB B
ON A.AColumn1 = B.BColumn1 AND A.AColumn2 = B.BColumn2
inner join TableC C
ON A.AColumn1 = C.CColumn1 AND A.AColumn2 = C.CColumn2
inner join TableD d
```

But when there are three tables, and all the 2 inner join conditions are related to two or more Columns, I got the trouble.

Linq SQL Example:

```
var query = from A in TableA
join B from TableB
on new {Column1 = A.AColunm1, Column2 = A.AColunm2} equals 
   new {Column1 = B.BColunm1, Column2 = B.BColunm2}
join C from TableC
on new {Column1 = A.AColunm1, Column2 = B.BColunm2} equals 
   new {Column1 = C.CColunm1, Column2 = C.CColunm2}
select new {A.AColunm1, C.CColunm2};
```

The error will happen at the *join C*

Comment: Make sure you have given alias in both left side and right side whilst joining with multiple columns. i.e: PER_ID, PER_INDID

Comment: Both names and **types** of the left and right side must match. I see the names match, check the **types** - for instance one is nullable and the other is not, etc.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @PrinceT,  Here my given alias name are the same of the left and right.

Comment: @PrinceT, Thanks your kindly information. You got the point. I had checked my referred column types and all the Tables.  At last, in the TableC, I have a type of  int? to CColumn2, while the BColumn2 and the AColumn2 are in type of int.

Comment: And the right Linq SQL should be the following                                         var query = from A in TableA
join B from TableB
on new {Column1 = A.AColunm1, Column2 = A.AColunm2} equals 
   new {Column1 = B.BColunm1, Column2 = B.BColunm2}
join C from TableC
on new {Column1 = A.AColunm1, Column2 = B.BColunm2} equals 
   new {Column1 = C.CColunm1, Column2 = C.CColunm2.Value}
select new {A.AColunm1, C.CColunm2};